# How to make function?

Tags: python, pandas

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
sns.distplot(df['Age'])
plt.subplot(122)
df['Age'].plot.box(figsize=(16,5))
plt.show()
```

The only changes from one plot to another is the variable name (Age, Day_Scheduled...).  You could create a function that accepts the dataframe df and the variable's name as arguments and creates a plot. This way, every time you need to do this exact same plot, but using different variables, you can do just by calling this custom function, using something like

`function_name(dataframe = df, variable = "Day_Scheduled")`

Comment: What is your *question*? It sounds like you're trying to tell someone how to do something. Is this the advice you received from someone else? Are you posting to try to understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function like this:

```
def make_figure(dataframe=df, variable="Day_Scheduled"):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(121)
    sns.distplot(dataframe[variable])
    plt.subplot(122)
    dataframe[variable].plot.box(figsize=(16,5))
    plt.show()
```

And call it like this to generate a new figure for each variable:

```
field_names = ["Age", "Day_Scheduled"]
for name in field_names:
    make_figure(df, name)
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-132-c9ca97246700>", line 1
    def make_figure(dataframe=df, variable="Day_Scheduled")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could do just that!

```
def my_plotting_function(df, variable):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(121)
    sns.distplot(df[variable])
    plt.subplot(122)
    df[variable].plot.box(figsize=(16,5))
    plt.show()
```